# PDM to PCM conversion workload on 32-bit micro (such as STM32)

Tags: audio, stm32

Can anyone provide a rough estimate of the processing power required to do PDM (e.g. audio from MEMS microphone) to PCM conversion on a 32-bit microcontroller ?
Specifically - I see ST provides a PDM to PCM library (with audio rate up to 48KHz) for the STM32F407 which is an ARM Cortex-M4 at up to 168MHz: I wonder how many processor MHz this PDM-PCM conversion may eat up.
And - would PDM-to-PCM be doable on the less powerful STM32L1 (Cortex-M3 at 32MHz) - perhaps at a degraded audio rate as I'm not looking for top quality audio.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the analog option? Just add an RC filter to the output of the MEMS microphone, connect the filter output to the built-in ADC, and let the analog electronics do the filtering for you. A ~4 kHz cut-off frequency (say, 3.9kΩ R plus 100 nF C) would give you telephone-quality audio, and should be pretty cheap to build, with a small board footprint.

Comment: Yes I've been thinking about that too. But I was wondering whether a simple RC would be enough to get something decent. Telephone-quality audio would be ok, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: It should be. In theory the RC filter is not nearly selective enough to prevent aliasing. But in practice, I don't expect it to be a problem, particularly if you sample at a fairly high rate (say a decade above Nyquist, i.e. 80 kHz) and then apply a small digital filter. Assuming the microphone itself has no frequency response above, say, 10 kHz, then the only sources of aliasing would be the harmonics from the square wave and the noise, and these should have little energy.